# Does Asymptotic Stability Imply the Existence of a Lyapunov Function for a Nonlinear System?

Tags: stability-in-odes, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

For a linear time-invariant system $\dot x = Ax,$ the inverse Lyapunov theorem asserts that if the origin is asymptotically stable, then a Lyapunov function in the form $V(x) = x^\top P x$ for some positive definite function $P.$

Is there a similar result for nonlinear systems? Namely, for a nonlinear dynamical system in the form $\dot x = f(x)$ such that the origin $x=0$ is globally asymptotically stable, is the existence of a Lyapunov function guaranteed? (Of course, even if the Lyapunov function exists, it might be very tricky to find.) If the existence of a Lyapunov function is not guaranteed, then are there any known counter-examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is Theorem 4.17 in Khalil's [book](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Khalil-Nonlinear-Systems-3rd-Edition/PGM298535.html):

Let $x=0$ be an asymptotically stable equilibrium of $\dot{x}=f(x)$. Then there is a smooth positive definite function $V(x)$ and a continuous positive definite function $W(x)$ such that:
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\,f(x)=-W(x)
$$

(I have omitted some details)